# Discover missing foreign keys and/or indexes

Tags: postgresql, database-design, index, foreign-key

We have a pretty big database (around 700GB of data), which has been inherited to us, and has had several DBAs. With time we've realized that there are several missing foreign keys and indexes.

I'd like to know if there is some automated way of discovering such potential missing keys/indexes using some kind of log parsing or something alike.

Comment: If you can find an algorithm which defines where _should_ a FK be, then it can be done, yes.  Furthermore, looking at your JOINs you can spot candidates, too.  Indexes on all these columns are usually a must, but there might be others that would make sense.

Comment: Thanks @dezso, actually looking on JOINs is one of the things I was thinking on, but cannot be done on code side, as there are way too many apps using the DB. That's why I was wondering on a DB approach to "peek" into query history / logs or something like that.

Comment: If you don't log everything already, you can start it now, collect the data and then analyze later - be prepared with free disk space for the log amount that might be generated.  A database-wide `log_statement = all` might be needed.  Don't forget to switch it off later :)

Comment: @dezso Ok, we'll start logging for sometime (depending) on free disk (as you suggested), but what tool could we use later for log processing?

Comment: You could use `grep -i join` :D  Seriously, `pgbadger` could help you finding the typical queries - with some parameters, you may find most of the interesting ones.

Comment: @dezso will look for `pgbadger`

Comment: When I had to do that, the first step was to use the data dictionary to discover what PKs, FKs and indexes I did have.  The next step was to reverse engineer an ER model (not a relational model) of the underlying subject matter.  A tool called PowerDesigner had some reverse engineering features built in, and I got a lot of help from the subject matter experts.  There are several steps after that, but this is a start.  When you do database archaeology, you have to do a lot of digging.

Comment: As far as the apps goes, start listening to the complaints, and acting on some of them.  As soon as people realize you are responsive, complaints will come pouring out of the woodwork.

Comment: Are you actually looking for undeclared FKs?  An FK is an FK, whether the database builder declared it or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I remembered seeing a query sometime ago in a post so quick searching resulted in:

```
CREATE FUNCTION pg_temp.sortarray(int2[]) returns int2[] as '
  SELECT ARRAY(
      SELECT $1[i]
        FROM generate_series(array_lower($1, 1), array_upper($1, 1)) i
    ORDER BY 1
  )
' language sql;

  SELECT conrelid::regclass
         ,conname
         ,reltuples::bigint
    FROM pg_constraint
         JOIN pg_class ON (conrelid = pg_class.oid)
   WHERE contype = 'f'
         AND NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT 1
             FROM pg_index
            WHERE indrelid = conrelid
                  AND pg_temp.sortarray(conkey) = pg_temp.sortarray(indkey)
         )
ORDER BY reltuples DESC
;
```

From http://mlawire.blogspot.nl/2009/08/postgresql-indexes-on-foreign-keys.html

That will give you what you want.

And also found https://github.com/pgexperts/pgx_scripts/blob/master/indexes/fk_no_index.sql but I haven't used this myself.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/60050)

Comment: You're right, thanks. I've updated the answer to include the query.

Comment: @KárolyNagy great tip for missing indexes from foreign keys, will add to the log/pgbadger procedure

Comment: The pgexperts scripts have worked quite well for me in production. They have an added benefit of being provided by major contributors to PostgreSQL as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is hard to do generically without knowing naming conventions.

Assuming all tables start with **t_** and assuming foreign key columns end with **_id** then this query will (at least) list most foreign keys, both ones that are missing and present.  It will also suggest the name of the destination table.

```
WITH source_data AS
(
    SELECT table_name AS source_table_name, column_name AS source_column_name
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_schema = 'public'
    AND table_name LIKE 't_%'
    AND column_name LIKE '%\_id'
), target_data AS
(
    SELECT distinct table_name as target_table_name
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_schema = 'public'
    AND table_name like 't_%'
), data_to_find AS
(
    SELECT *, CASE WHEN target_table_name IS NULL THEN 'No Match' ELSE 'Match' END AS match_found
    FROM source_data
    LEFT JOIN target_data ON ('t_' || LEFT(source_column_name, -3)) = target_table_name
), foreign_keys AS
(
    SELECT
        tc.constraint_name, tc.table_name, kcu.column_name, 
        ccu.table_name AS foreign_table_name,
        ccu.column_name AS foreign_column_name 
    FROM 
        information_schema.table_constraints AS tc 
        JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu
          ON tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
        JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu
          ON ccu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
    WHERE constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY'
)
SELECT CASE WHEN constraint_name IS NULL THEN 'No Foreign Key' ELSE 'Foreign Key Found' end AS foreign_key, * FROM data_to_find
LEFT JOIN foreign_keys ON 
(
    data_to_find.source_table_name = foreign_keys.table_name 
    AND
    data_to_find.source_column_name = foreign_keys.column_name
)
ORDER BY foreign_key, match_found, source_table_name, source_column_name
```